# Laravel relationship: trying to get non-object. Expected behaviour or bug?

Tags: laravel

First things first please let me outline a skeleton of my database structure and relationships:

**Database**

```
stores [ country and city are foreign keys to places.id ]
-------------------
id | country | city
-------------------
1  | 1       | 2
2  | 1       | 3

=============================================

places
--------------------
id | google_place_id 
--------------------
1  | pd0nf892nd0s 
2  | icnsy63dnaxa 
3  | 7m34bcs19cnj

=============================================

place_name_map
------------------------------------------
id | place_id | language | value
------------------------------------------
1  | 1        | en       | United Kingdom
2  | 1        | fr       | le Royaume-Uni
3  | 2        | en       | London
4  | 2        | fr       | Londres
5  | 3        | en       | Edinburgh
6  | 3        | fr       | Édimbourg
```

**Store.php**

```
public function country() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Place','id','country');
}

public function city() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Place','id','city');
}

//my workaround relationships to the possible bug
public function tCountry() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Place','id','country');
}

public function tCity() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Place','id','city');
}
```

**Place.php**

```
public function name() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\PlaceNameMap')->where('language',\App::getLocale());
}
```

So, now say we're query building to display the details of a store in the user's locale

```
$store = Store::where('id',1)
         ->with(['country.name','city.name'])
         ->firstOrFail();
dd($store->country->name->value);
```

This gives me an *ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object*

Whereas this

```
$store = Store::where('id',1)
         ->with(['tCountry.name','tCity.name'])
         ->firstOrFail();
dd($store->tCountry->name->value);
```

Returns 'United Kingdom' correctly, assuming the user locale is set to 'en'.

When I die and dump `$store` in both cases they are identical except obviously country = tCountry etc.

Usually we can use column names fine when eager loading relationships so why does this seem to be an exception? Is it a bug or expected behaviour?

Comment: can you identify `country` is null or `name` is null?

Comment: No, `$store->country` simply returns the integer from the database column in the store table, so `1` in the case of the example. Which is why I'm stumped that when I dd(), the relationship seems to exist fine

Comment: It's expected behaviour, properties with the same name have priority over relations. Why not to rename columns to city_id and country_id?

Comment: ok I get it, you have country in stores table, so when you access $store->country, it returns the attribute of this store in stores table. that's expected behavior, so you probably shouldn't use same name both on attribute and on relationship

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, makes sense now. Will do that Dmitri, which is actually the 'Laravel' way of doing things now I think about it. Thanks both for your help.

Comment: if you are storing a foriegn key, it's better use country_id and city_id, and you can avoid this problem.